# array_push() function not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a web application in Laravel. The below code is not from the application but gives you a simple idea of the problem I am having.

The following code works

```
public $my_users = [];  //This is outside function

$users = [];
$users = User::all();
$this->my_users = $users;
```

That's pretty simple, works fine. However, i want to be able to loop through all of the users and add ones of my choosing like so:

```
public $my_users = [];  //This is outside function

$users = [];
$all_users = User::all();
foreach ($all_users as $user)
{
    array_push($users, $user);
}
$this->my_users = $users;
```

Again, what I am doing here has no logic behind it, it's just an example.

In this case both pieces of code should have the same result. However, the second piece of code isn't working. It seems to be the array_push function that isn't working here. is there any reason why this is? What am I to do here?

Comment: Whats the result of var_dump($users); ?

Comment: It seems like you are looping through an array to create another array and then assigning in the global array. Why you are doing that? Instead can't you directly assign the array?

Comment: I feel like there's something missing here. There's no part of either snippets that should be failing unless the users table is empty (in which case the first snippet will have an object and the second one an empty array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User::all();` returns a type `collection (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)`. 
So first block of code you delcared an array `$users = [];` and immediately override it with:

```
$this->my_users = User::all();
```

So you're basically assigning a collection to `$this->my_users`.

2nd block of code you are looping through the collection and assign it to the array.

```
$this->my_users = [
   //instance of App\User 1,
   //instance of App\User 2 etc
];
```

Try `dd` the result and you should be able to see a clearer picture.

Comment: So what I need to do is create an instance of a collection and then add to that collection. Do you know how to do this? I've tried $users = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection; didn't work.

Comment: You can just add it to a normal array and convert it to collection by doing `collect($usersArray)`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have a collection all_users, how do I create another collection so I can add specific users from the all_users collection to it? I can't add instances of all_users to an array.

Comment: Any reason you would want to add a collection into another collection? Anyway you can do `$newCollection = collect();` to create a new collection. Then you can use `$newCollection->push($all_users);`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's query results are always a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections#available-methods) so if filtering is what you really need then do:

```
$users = Users::all()->filter(function ($u) { /* conditions to accept the user */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the default helper of the Laravel instead of array_push

```
array_add()
```

See the documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-add

Answer (score -1):

`$users.push($user);`
i think this is how you push into your array

Comment: It's not though

Comment: my bad. that's how you do it in javascript but not in laravel i guess